# Should I send my manuscript again if I forgot the synopsis after sending it to a publisher?

Tags: email, publisher, submitting-work, synopsis

I emailed the manuscript and everything the guidelines said, and then realised the next morning I forgot to attatch the synopsis with it. I looked over the guidelines while I did the email. This is my first time submitting a manuscript to a publisher.

I'm new at this, and I don't know when I should resend it. They allow the first week of each month to submit. If I don't get a response within three months, it means they won't go forward with it. Should I wait until then?

Comment: Resend – the whole package, as Mark Baker explains – **immediately**. In most email software your two emails will be presented together. If you are quick enough, the editor will receive your second email before they get to the first one.

Answer (score 7):

The publisher essentially wants to know two things about you.

1. Can you tell a good story.
2. Can you behave professionally and deliver on your commitments.

Omitting the summary obviously reflects badly on the second point. Following up promptly to correct the mistake mitigates the problem as best you can.

But if you resend, resend the whole package. Don't expect that they are going to dig through their whole slush pile to find your first mail to add a synopsis to it. Send them a complete correct package with a note explaining and telling them to throw your original mail away.

Comment: @what Good point. I edited to be neutral about delivery method. (After all, answers are supposed to be useful to as many people as possible.)